# Building JNI Shared Library from native code under Windows

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Can I build shared library from native code (.so file, to be used in JNI) under Windows-(XP or 7)? If yes how ?  What if it is NDK for Android?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refer to this book: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

Instructions for compiling a JNI shared library on Windows: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#27008 (On Windows they use the extension .dll, not .so)

**Update:** Oracle has taken the above link down, but it can be viewed at http://web.archive.org/web/20110623094757/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#27008

These instructions are for the Visual C++ compiler; if you use another compiler look up in its manual how to compile shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the same (build the library using VC++ on Windows ) if I am using NDK for Android? I am sorry I did not mention clearly in  my question that I also want to know this in case of NDK for android

Comment: No. If you are compiling for android you need a compiler that can generate binaries for Android; you cannot use the Visual C++ compiler because it compiles for Windows only. Although, you may be able to use the Visual Studio IDE thanks to plugins such as http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/